# How can I avoid creating the same element in my database using while using promises?

Tags: promise, duplicates

I'm having issue with duplicates and promises.

1. I'm fetching GitHub pull requests for every organization repository at the same time. While doing so, I might stumble upon a GitHub profile that I did not save yet in my database.
2. So I need to save this profile with a specific and unique ID, that is generated with the profile GitHub ID and the organization ID.
3. When I try to create a new element with a unique ID already saved, my database is throwing an error (which is expected), but when I am using promises, my database does not throw any error and creates multiple elements with the same unique ID. Because I ask my DB to save them at the same time.

Do you know how to avoid creating duplicates of unique elements while using promises?